# Can Kubernetes Jobs helpful in executing time consuming micro-services in background?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

In my web application, I have certain tasks like uploading files that consume a lot of time, So is it a better idea to run it as a Kubernetes job?

I didn't find any suitable use-cases to execute a task like that

I have my server running in Kubernetes pod, for some time-consuming task, I just want to execute it on the separate job  to balance the load and run it asynchronously

Comment: Are you looking for Cron Jobs https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

Comment: NO run to completion job

Comment: We really have no way of knowing what application you have, or what requirements are in front of you. Therefore this is more of an opinion or guesswork question.

Comment: Its a web application

Answer (score 1):

No, this would require some kind of background task execution library for your web framework or whatever. Jobs are maybe a building block for that, but definitely not the whole thing. Look at tools like Gearman, Celery, Resque, etc.

Comment: I saw that example of the Message Queue system with Celery kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/… . Can you please elaborate on how it's helpful in my case of web framework